# How to show first page as half in pageView builder flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am using `PageView.builder` for making custom calendar. The problem is that page items are starting from the center.

[image: this is the app image]

Note : `PageView.builder` is used where i am using reverse property. Also items are starting from the center but not from the right as page is starting from center.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building the calendar date widgets using Row, you can use Row's mainAxisAlignment property
like this

```
Row(
     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
     children: [
     
         ],
  ),
```